# How to calculate the output of ns() function in R by hand

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, splines, basis-function

`ns()` function in R can generate the natural cubic spline basis matrix. I checked the reference but still do not know how to calculate such matrix by hand.

For example, I have `x = (-2.377, 0.029, 0.106, 2.184)`. Using `ns` function with `df =3`, I can get:

```
[1,]  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,]  0.2534264 0.5250116 -0.2672809
[3,]  0.3119701 0.5053060 -0.2565989
[4,] -0.1665931 0.3393594  0.8272338

attr(,"degree")
[1] 3

attr(,"knots")
33.33333% 66.66667% 
0.029     0.106 

attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] -2.377  2.184

attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

Can anybody tell me how to calculate each value in the matrix?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I had a similar question, so I made a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8ozpvn5O1euQtNcaiMLqa-QP4Q_PBpoAX7TgeKYCkU/edit?usp=sharing) which walks through the calculation! Let me know what you think. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcWXR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcWXR.png)